# Double instance of tinyMCE on one page

Tags: php, jquery, html, laravel-5, tinymce

I have been trying to add two instances of the TinyMCE editor into one page and I couldn't, so I did a bit of research and tried to separate the `id`'s for each `<textarea>`. For this I added this code to my JS:

JS

```
  tinymce.init({
        selector: "#mytextarea1",
        mode : "exact",
        elements :"area1",
        menubar: false,
        statusbar: false,
        height : 240,

    });

    tinymce.init({
        selector: "#mytextarea2",
        mode : "exact",
        elements :"area2",
        menubar: false,
        statusbar: false,
        height : 240,

    });
```

Since I am working with laravel 5, this is the code that I used for the forms:

Laravel - Blade

TinyMCE Instance #1 (Works)

```
{!! Form::textarea('noteContent',null,array( 'id'=>'mytextarea1')) !!}
```

TinyMCE Instance #2 (Doesn't work, instead shows normal textarea box)

```
{!! Form::textarea('noteContentEdit',null,array( 'id'=>'mytextarea2')) !!}
```

Am I doing something wrong? I read I had to make sure the `selector`'s are different in each element and I thought I had, but I must be doing something wrong, Thank you in advance.

P.S [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9011721/multiple-instances-of-tinymce-on-fields-with-same-id) is the SO question I tried to incorporate into my  problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay so all I had to do was edit the jQuery code to be this:

jQuery

```
tinymce.init({
            editor_selector : "mceCreate",
            mode: "textareas",
            menubar: false,
            statusbar: false,
            height : 240,

        });

tinymce.init({
            editor_selector : "mceEdit",
            mode: "textareas",
            menubar: false,
            statusbar: false,
            height : 240,

            });
```

Adding an `editor_selector` attribute to each and instead of `id`'s in the  tags, I used classes. I also changed the `mode` attribute to `textarea`.. Now it works.